# Joining a domain is no longer possible. Windows Server 2016 - Windows 10 22H2

Tags: windows, active-directory

I can't connect computers to the domain. It pops up when I try to connect my computer to the domain(Windows Server 2016 - Windows 10):

[image]

*This user cannot log in due to account restrictions*

I tried on 2 computers and two admin accounts with AD.

*Fehler beim Beitritt des Computers "" zur Domäne "". Fehlercode: "1327".*

[image]

*1327 052F Login failed: User account limitation. Possible
Reasons for this: empty passwords are not allowed,
Login time restrictions, or a policy restriction has been imposed*

Where exactly to look for the source of problems, where to start?

Comment: Check in gpo that your accounts are in a group that is eligible to join to domain. Are your account real admin accounts? Check if they're limited by join quota

Comment: First, make sure the domain user you are using for the domain join is healthy. Can you log into a domain joined computer with it? Next make sure the domain user has appropriate permission to the domain computer object you intend to join. Many of these permissions depend on how your environment is configured. Log into the non-domain PC with a local admin account, then use the domain user credential when performing the join operation. You should also reference the NetSetup.log file for any additional errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing from the "protect users" group helped with my problem. Now I can join the domain.

[image]